# simulate state space and action sapce of QL in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am new in modeling using Simulink, I want to simulate ql using Matlab. i don't know how can simulate state space and action space of QL in Matlab?

I tried to find any paper but unfortunately, I did not find any paper explain about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.